# Color code alternate rows based on date in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, unique, conditional-formatting

I would like to shade the rows based on alternate dates in google sheets. For example, the first row will always be unshaded, following that in the picture below, there is a new date "2021-03-19" in rows 2 and 3, hence they need to be shaded. Following that, next date, 2021-01-01 does not need to be and so on.

I have recently started using google sheets, not sure whether it can be achieved using any in built command.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you define what a new date is?   You can use conditional formatting with a custom formula.   By comparing the date to today's date, you can highlight if it is less than x days before today. Without that definition, here is an example =$E2 > (Today() - 5)  This would dynamically highlight anything that is less than 5 days old, as it gets older than 5 days it won't be highlighted anymore.

Comment: @KrispinMiller: Thanks, sorry, by new date, i meant anything that's not the same as before. For example date is 2 & 3 row is different than previous row (1st row), hence they need to get highlighted. For 4th  and 5th rows, its different than previous row (3rd), hence that does not need to be highlighted and so on.

Comment: as @player0 demonstrated this is very possible, but as a new-ish sheets user, you might not be aware that Cond. formatting like that has the potential to significiantly slow down your sheet if it gets large (greater than 3000 rows and i think you'll start to feel it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
=ISEVEN(MATCH($A1, UNIQUE($A$1:$A), 0))
```

[image]